# Neo4j return boolean shows blank value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This might be intentional behavior, but it appears returning a boolean attribute from a node returns a blank value unless it is cast to string, for example

`return myNode.isValSet` returns a blank value

whereas

`return toString(myNode.isValSet)` returns true or false

Is it possible to return the boolean value in cypher without the cast to string?

Comment: Are you sure that `myNode.isValSet` is set? what happens if you just `RETURN myNode`?

Comment: Not intentional. I think this bug affects version 3.2.1, should be fixed in 3.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your scenario here. This is only a bug in the output of Neo4j Browser. Look:

```
CREATE (myNode {isValSet:true}) // create myNode with isValSet = true
```

Querying:

```
MATCH (myNode)
RETURN myNode.isValSet
```

The result in the "Table" mode is blank as described by you:

[image: "Table" mode]

But when I change the visualization to "Text" the `true` value is shown:

[image: "Text" mode]

Searching in the neo4j-browser Github hepo I found [a closed issue about it](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/587) and a [commit fixing it](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/pull/588). This fix will probably available in a next release.

Comment: 3.2.2, which was released earlier in July, should have the fix already.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I'm unable to upgrade to 3.2.2 because the PowerShell Module is not digitally signed:(